# Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint while using lambda as docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, asp.net-core-3.1

I am writing a lambda in C# .NET Core. I am publishing this lambda as docker to AWS. My docker file is:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /app

COPY Lambda.PowerPointProcessor.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore Lambda.PowerPointProcessor.csproj

COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:3.1 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/out ./

ENTRYPOINT ["Lambda.PowerPointProcessor::Lambda.PowerPointProcessor.Function::FunctionHandler"]
```

After publishing the lambda, when i run it, i get the following error:

```
START RequestId: 7ae4e657-df66-41d9-b9ff-633aab95601a Version: $LATEST
IMAGE   Launch error: exec: "Lambda.PowerPointProcessor::Lambda.PowerPointProcessor.Function::FunctionHandler": executable file not found in $PATH  Entrypoint: [Lambda.PowerPointProcessor::Lambda.PowerPointProcessor.Function::FunctionHandler]  Cmd: [Lambda.PowerPointProcessor::Lambda.PowerPointProcessor.Function::FunctionHandler] WorkingDir: [/app]IMAGE Launch error: exec: "Lambda.PowerPointProcessor::Lambda.PowerPointProcessor.Function::FunctionHandler": executable file not found in $PATH  Entrypoint: [Lambda.PowerPointProcessor::Lambda.PowerPointProcessor.Function::FunctionHandler]  Cmd: [Lambda.PowerPointProcessor::Lambda.PowerPointProcessor.Function::FunctionHandler] WorkingDir: [/app]END RequestId: 7ae4e657-df66-41d9-b9ff-633aab95601a
REPORT RequestId: 7ae4e657-df66-41d9-b9ff-633aab95601a  Duration: 0.93 ms   Billed Duration: 1 ms   Memory Size: 256 MB Max Memory Used: 2 MB   
RequestId: 7ae4e657-df66-41d9-b9ff-633aab95601a Error: exec: "Lambda.PowerPointProcessor::Lambda.PowerPointProcessor.Function::FunctionHandler": executable file not found in $PATH
Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint
```

I believe i am missing something very basic here. Any help would be much appreciated.